# Update Value Automatically Based on dropdown selection and change

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When I select 'Sole trader' option & '£ 0k – £ 85k' option from both dropdown and select 'yes' radio button - getting right answer i.e. £ 700

But after that i again goes up and change dropdown option (change to Partnership) then value in div AccountsQuote need to update automatically i.e. £ 900

But it is not updating - need to do yes - no selection to update value.

I need to change it automatically as per my input, even after change

**Below is my code:**

```js
$("#businesstype").change(function() {
  callmethod();
});

$("#turnover").change(function() {
  callmethod();
});

function callmethod() {
  $('input[type=radio][name=accounts]').change(function() {
    if (this.value == 'Yes') {

      var businesstype = $('#businesstype').val();
      var turnover = $('#turnover').val();

      if (businesstype == "Sole trader" && turnover == "£ 0k – £ 85k") {
        document.getElementById("AccountsQuote").innerHTML = '£ 700';
      } else if (businesstype == "Sole trader" && turnover == "£ 85k – £ 99k") {
        document.getElementById("AccountsQuote").innerHTML = '£ 850';
      } else if (businesstype == "Partnership" && turnover == "£ 0k – £ 85k") {
        document.getElementById("AccountsQuote").innerHTML = '£ 900';
      }
    } else if (this.value == 'No') {
      document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = '£ 0';
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <div id="businesstype-group" class="form-group">
    <label for="businesstype">What type of business are you?</label><br>
    <select id='businesstype' name='businesstype'>
      <option value="" disabled selected>-- Choose --</option>
      <option value="Sole trader">Sole trader</option>
      <option value="Partnership">Partnership</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="turnover-group" class="form-group">
    <label for="turnover">What is your annual turnover?</label><br>
    <select id='turnover' name="turnover">
      <option value="" disabled selected>-- Choose --</option>
      <option value="£ 0k – £ 85k">£ 0k – £ 85k</option>
      <option value="£ 85k – £ 99k">£ 85k – £ 99k</option>
      <option value="£ 100k – £ 149k">£ 100k – £ 149k</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="accounts-group" class="form-group">
    <label for="accounts">Do you require Accounts & Tax Returns services?</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="accountsyes" name="accounts" value="Yes">
    <label for="accountsyes">Yes</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="accountsno" name="accounts" value="No">
    <label for="accountsno">No</label>
  </div>

  <div id="AccountsQuote"></div>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The problem is, that you have the change event handler for the yes/no radio buttons included in `callmethod()`. You need to remove that, so that the function also works, when the radio buttons aren't changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move change handler out of callmethod function. So that callmethod function will just do calculation based on selected input. Here is example.

```js
$("#businesstype").change(function() {
  callmethod();
});

$("#turnover").change(function() {
  callmethod();
});

$('input[type=radio][name=accounts]').change(function() {
    callmethod();
});

function callmethod() {
    var radioVal = $('input[type=radio][name=accounts]:checked').val();
    if (radioVal == 'Yes') {

      var businesstype = $('#businesstype').val();
      var turnover = $('#turnover').val();

      if (businesstype == "Sole trader" && turnover == "£ 0k – £ 85k") {
        document.getElementById("AccountsQuote").innerHTML = '£ 700';
      } else if (businesstype == "Sole trader" && turnover == "£ 85k – £ 99k") {
        document.getElementById("AccountsQuote").innerHTML = '£ 850';
      } else if (businesstype == "Partnership" && turnover == "£ 0k – £ 85k") {
        document.getElementById("AccountsQuote").innerHTML = '£ 900';
      }
    } else if (radioVal == 'No') {
      document.getElementById("AccountsQuote").innerHTML = '£ 0';
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <div id="businesstype-group" class="form-group">
    <label for="businesstype">What type of business are you?</label><br>
    <select id='businesstype' name='businesstype'>
      <option value="" disabled selected>-- Choose --</option>
      <option value="Sole trader">Sole trader</option>
      <option value="Partnership">Partnership</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="turnover-group" class="form-group">
    <label for="turnover">What is your annual turnover?</label><br>
    <select id='turnover' name="turnover">
      <option value="" disabled selected>-- Choose --</option>
      <option value="£ 0k – £ 85k">£ 0k – £ 85k</option>
      <option value="£ 85k – £ 99k">£ 85k – £ 99k</option>
      <option value="£ 100k – £ 149k">£ 100k – £ 149k</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="accounts-group" class="form-group">
    <label for="accounts">Do you require Accounts & Tax Returns services?</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="accountsyes" name="accounts" value="Yes">
    <label for="accountsyes">Yes</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="accountsno" name="accounts" value="No">
    <label for="accountsno">No</label>
  </div>

  <div id="AccountsQuote"></div>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```